# How can I manage circularly @Inject in jax-rs?

Tags: java, jax-rs, inject

I'm writting an application in pure jax-rs (without any framework like Spring or something like that).
My application is structured in domains. So supposing to build a TODO list application with login, there're 2 domains:

- one for managing the TODO list (CRUD on database)
- one for managing user (registration and login).
  Each domain has the own controller and service and one or more repositories.

Because in the future the application will be split into different aplications, I would like to separate logically the database: the user domain doesn't include any entity/repository classes of other domains.

For doing this, I suppose that the best approach is to share only service interface through `@Inject`. In fact, the service is implemented the business logic and security checks without exposing the database entities. So, for retrieve all information of other domains, a service needs to ask to another service.

Grafically:

```
user
 |- UserController (@Inject UserService)
 |- UserService (@Inject UserRepository, @Inject TodoService)
 `- UserRepository
todo
 |- TodoController (@Inject TodoService)
 |- TodoService (@Inject TodoRepository, @Inject UserService)
 `- TodoRepository
```

As you can see, every Service has injected the other ones.
Anyway, at startup, the JBoss server fails because the dependencies are circular.

```
UserService <-> TodoService
```

For example, in this usecase, UserService, on login, after checking the credentials invoke `TodoService.countList(user.id)` for fetching the count of the lists. Instead TodoService, needs to fetch user information (like username and so on), in order to fill the response with user info too. This is just an example.

So, I would like to keep repository segregation and use service interface in order to separate the business login.
I also would like to keep controller as simple as possibile without including service of other domains.

Comment: Can you give more information about what methods are used by both services? Having a circular dependency is usually discouraged but can be relevant, it depends. However, if you're using CDI, circular dependency shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: recommend injecting needed services at controller level. Having services depend on each other will get you in trouble in the long run, even if CDI would allow your circular dependencies. if you have one layer "simple as possible", then you're just pushing unneeded complexity to service level, so mess is bigger.

Comment: I would probably have just one TodoAppController, which would get both TodoService and UserService services injected. Since both are needed for one function, this is the clearest way to go IMO. Service classes would then expose needed services per domain, but would not be dependent on each other.

Comment: I can inject the services in the controller. But in this way, the orchestration is made at controller level. So, this way binds the interface with the orchestration because the controller know where the information lives.
I would like to put all business logic (the orchestration is business logic from my point of view) in the service.